# How can I change the resolution of Iriun 4K Webcam to 1080p on linux?

Tags: usb, camera

I would like to change the resolution of **iriun 4K webcam to 1080p** on **Arch Linux**. My phone supports upto **4K**

[image: Iriun Client]

It shows resolutions upto 4K but does not change it remains 640x480.

Comment: This question is clearly about Linux software even if a [Android] phone is involved. Why do you post in on a site dedicated to Android? Your answer shows that your problem has nothing to to with Android.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Close OBS Studio** if running then
2. Enter this command `sudo v4l2loopback-ctl set-caps "video/x-raw,format=UYVY, width=1920, height=1080" /dev/video0`
   *Note : **/dev/video0** is the name of your virtual device*

This worked for me.

Thanks